# How do I connect an image, with a user-defined bridge?

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I am starting of with an image of a Spring Boot application, that is depending on a PostgresSql database. So the Spring Boot container won't run, if there is no database for it to connect to.

The database is running but, as the `--link`option is now [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge) in docker. How can I connect these two containers when I can't get SpringBoot to run and then do the `docker network connect my-net postgres` command.

I created both images with separate `Dockerfiles` is this maybe just possible using the `docker-compose` approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use a docker compose file to define your services. Using a docker compose file you can use the [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) option:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile-web
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
  postgres-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile-postgres-db
```

You can also define [networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) on the docker compose file to connect the container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile-web
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - backend-net
  postgres-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile-postgres-db
    networks:
      - backend-net

networks:
  backend-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thank for the clarification! I'll try the docker-compose approach. But, there is no way anymore to do it with separate Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 3):

First, start using a user-defined bridge network. This way you don't have to use `--link` which is considered legacy and the containers will be able to communicate by using their names. This is something which the default bridge network doesn't provide.

> From: [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)
>
> ### Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge
>
> - User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

Second, you can do it "manually" by running `docker` commands in the appropriate order / depending on your case, but as Sebastian has demonstrated in the `docker-compose` file, it is much easier to handle it that way.